Conditional formatting JSON not behaving as expected
I'm fairly new to SharePoint JSON. I have a simple JSON to change the value of a column based on the value of another column:
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if([$Persona] == 'Developer', 'A Developer is any person who has a responsibility to write code for application building, continuous delivery, automated testing, data analytics or vulnerability reviews.', 'N/A')"
}

Even though an item in the list has Developer as the value of the Persona column, the alternate text (N/A) is always displayed.
What am I doing wrong here? Also, is it possible to do an if else in SP JSON?

You have to use the correct internal name of Persona column in the JSON. Follow this article to get the correct internal name: https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/. Let me know if this works for you.

What is the column/data type of "Persona" column?

Persona column is just a single line text type

When I follow the instructions on the linked page, the URL after filtering is:
https://xxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/DevSecOps/Lists/Persona%20Descriptions/AllItems.aspx?id=%2Fsites%2FDevSecOps%2FLists%2FPersona%20Descriptions%2FArchitecture%20and%20Design&viewid=4a46758d%2De978%2D4862%2Db7f0%2D74a4b07607b4&isAscending=true&sortField=LinkTitle&useFiltersInViewXml=1&FilterField1=LinkTitle&FilterValue1=Manager&FilterType1=Computed&FilterOp1=In
the filter field is listed as sortField=LinkTitle...
The filter works but if I replace [$Persona] with [$LinkTitle] I get the same error.

The problem was with the column. I had renamed the Title column to Persona. Creating a new column and rewriting the code with that column name worked. Thanks for putting me on the right track.

Great, glad it worked for you!

You have to use the correct internal name of your SharePoint list columns in the JSON formatting.
If you have renamed and using SharePoint default Title column, you have to use [$Title] in the JSON.
For any other custom columns you created in the SharePoint list, you can get correct internal name by following this article: How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?.
